# Start celery worker throws "no attribute 'worker_state_db'"

Tags: python, django, celery

When I am trying to start celery worker in Django app as:

```
celery -A myApp worker -l info
```

I get following error:

```
File "/home/alexander/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/envs/myApp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 134, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, k))

    AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'worker_state_db'
```

If you know how to solve it please write your idea!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The bug appears if an exception is raised while parsing settings. Such as when we set Django's `SECRET_KEY` (or any other setting) via an environment variable:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

To solve the problem you can switch back to:

```
SECRET_KEY = "asdfasdfasdf"
```

or use:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', '')
```

You can also find which setting caused the problem if you comment our the following line in `celery.py` file and start the worker again:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

Comment: Remove the line `app.config_from_object...` didn't work to debug the problem, but changing `SECRET_KEY = os.environ...` worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Strange, last time I had some variables which were loaded without get() and I managed to find each of them after commenting that line. Anyway, it is better to go through all the settings and inspect which of them are loaded with os.environ['xxxxx']

Comment: what if I need to put those variables in os.enviro ? @alexander

Comment: They are inside os environment. Just different method to get them out

Comment: Uncommenting the `app.config_from_object` helps pinpoint the error!

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error when one of the keys was missing in my config.json which was being loaded in settings.py (basically a missing key in settings.py).

Error text is totally irrelevant. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: I had this problem, there was a typo in my environment variable, `SECRETS_KEY` instead of `SECRET_KEY`

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add two things:

1. This is also true when you load settings from any configuration file, not essentially django's. The question is related purely to Celery.
2. Some explanation on origins of this cryptic error:

`worker_state_db` is a setting with a default value, so you shouldn't have to set it manually. An exception is raised because `Settings` are just empty and don't have any values, even the default ones. That said, we don't have the default config loaded. Somehow in Celery, the exception from parsing (the original one which caused the problem) is not propagated to the stderr when starting a worker. Hence, you get a message which doesn't tell you anything about a possible solution.

How to fix it?
For example, if you have `celeryconfig.py` where your celery app module is placed and you load settings from there via:

```
app.config_from_object('path.to.your.celery.module.celeryconfig')
```

Check your whole `celeryconfig.py` file for anything that could crash or cause the parser to crash (incompatible settings values?).

Comment: for me, config was loaded for sure, but I still encountered this issue in Celery 4.3.0

Answer (score 1):

I got this over and over while trying to configure celery with a dockerized django project. The solution was including `env_file` in docker-compose.yaml:

```
  celery:
    ...
    env_file: .env
```

Comment: This works well; I assume if you have different services then it must be they don't share the same environment?

Answer (score 1):

Celery (in general, not just in Django's case) tries to first load config from it's config file.

**Error cause:**

Celery loads config file, but **ANY** exception is raised. Celery will display this error message instead:

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'worker_state_db'
```

**Very common example:**

Let's say your config file expects `BROKER_PASSWORD` environment variable in your Celery config file.

```
broker_password = os.environ['BROKER_PASSWORD']
```

**BUT!!!**

You forgot to make env variable `BROKER_PASSWORD` available... this code will therefore raise `KeyError`.

This will confuse Celery, so above message will be shown.